# Como enviar HashMap<String,Integer> con Intent a otra Activity

Tags: android

¿Como puedo enviar un `Map<String,Integer>= new HashMap<>();` de una actividad a otra, mediante `Intent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es similar a como se realiza con otro tipo de datos:

```
Map<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hashmap", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

al recibirlo el `Bundle` en otra `Activity` sería:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Map<String,Integer> hashMap = (Map<String, Integer>)intent.getSerializableExtra("hashmap");
```